# ImportError of tensorflow module after activating tenserflow_env

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I am writing a code to convert labels to one-hot representation in Convolutional Neural Network. I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I have already created tenserflow_env and activated it but still I am getting this error.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
# Creating the validation set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

print("Splitting training set to create validation set..")

train_X, valid_X, train_Y, valid_Y = train_test_split(train_X, train_Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)

# Converting labels to one-hot representation
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
train_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(train_Y)                       
valid_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(valid_Y)

test_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(test_Y)`
```

Comment: It should be `from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical`

Comment: You missed `train_X` and `train_Y` variable. 
Use `train_X, train_Y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)` to define them

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Tensorflow hasn't been properly installed.If you think you have already installed it, try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow` to force reinstall tensorflow using **pip**.

*If you are using Virtual environments, make sure to run `jupyter-notebook` after you have that **tenserflow_env** activated*

***Happy Deep Learning!***

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have lot of errors itself. But what I understand is the below solution for it.

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

# Creating the validation set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_X, train_Y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)

test_Y = range(5)

print("Splitting training set to create validation set..")

train_X, valid_X, train_Y, valid_Y = train_test_split(train_X, train_Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)

# Converting labels to one-hot representation

train_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(train_Y)                       
valid_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(valid_Y)

test_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(test_Y)
print(test_Y_one_hot)
```

> output

```
Splitting training set to create validation set..
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```